# How to make sure pip is installed within virtual environment with venv pacakge?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am using venv library to create a virtual environment programmatically ( see code below) , the set up works  in my local machine (mac os) , but when i run this code in an ec2 instance on aws, the virtual environment is created but under bin folder there is no pip installed . the create command with_pip set to True, is what i assume does the pip install but not sure why it won't work in an ec2 instance.

app.py

```
import subprocess
import sys
import venv
import os

venv.create("ven", with_pip=True)

subprocess.call(['ven/bin/pip3', "install", "pandas"])
```

Comment: Does `python3 -m pip` work?

Comment: Before you solve the question,  you can use ** python3 -m pip install pandas** to install package.

Comment: @thanks. i was able to install the package by -> ven/bin/python -m pip install pandas. now , how do i use pandas or pandas command , as i'm not able to activate this virtual environment , where this pandas is installed.